# Android Studio on Mac, need to use custom version of SDK

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I've got a sample project for an OEM part from a Chinese manufacturer that uses a custom android.jar with some of their proprietary classes in it. The SDK is 4.0.3 API version 15 with Windows binaries for adb, etc..  I've got the project set up in Android Studio on my Mac, the classes are detected successfully, and it seems to build fine, but then it says "Unable to locate adb within SDK." I actually tried copying the mac adb binary from the regular up-to-date SDK dir but this didn't affect anything.  Any ideas?  I have no idea if there's anything truly "Windows only" involved here, or how to "mix and match" the parts of the SDK to get this to work.

If I choose the Custom SDK for the Module, and a modern SDK (i.e. API 22) for the Project, I can get rid of the "Unable to locate adb" error, but then instead I get "Error:android-validator: [GemvaryPortDemo] Incompatible version 14 of Android SDK Tools package. Min version is 19. Please, update it though SDK manager" presumably because the tools in the Custom SDK directory are very old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is, in fact, possible.  I needed to copy over `tools`, `platform-tools` and add `build-tools` from my regular, up-to-date, mac Android SDK. Now it builds just fine!